# Is there an intuition for the exterior calculus identity dd = 0

Tags: tag-removed

Considering an exterior derivative $d$, which may be discretized as the transpose of the boundary operator on a simplicial mesh, I have read and seen that $dd = 0$, but I have not seen an intuitive explanation of this result. I suspect this result is deeply entrenched in the fact that $d$ is defined on an *oriented* mesh.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the boundary of the boundary? The transpose of zero is zero.

Comment: Calculate some examples and you will see why $d^2=0$.

Comment: You could consider the quotation from Henri Cartan's Laudatio on receiving the degree of Doctor Honoris Causa From Oxford University in 1980. It is on the opening of Gelfand and Manin's Methods of Homological Algebra.

Comment: You may enjoy reading answers to these questions http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10574/ http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21024/what-is-the-exterior-derivative-intuitively

Comment: I can see through experimentation and examples that this is true, but there must be a geometric argument for why it is the case.