# How do I join the dots between the formal definition of exterior derivative and the intuition

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am self-studying differential forms, and I'd like to understand the proof of Stoke's theorem.

I have read through the document [here](https://github.com/dpiponi/forms/raw/master/forms.pdf) by [Dan Piponi](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1233/dan-piponi) and really liked his explanation of the exterior derivative as finding the boundary in the picture (section 4, page 6), but I have a hard time to connect this with the formal definition of the exterior derivative.

Reading through the comments of his answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21024/what-is-the-exterior-derivative-intuitively), I am not sure if the concept of 'finding the boundary in the picture' applies to just `xdy` or any differential forms?

Comment: two earlier MO questions are similar:  [one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21024/11260) and [two](https://mathoverflow.net/q/10574/11260) --- is there something left to answer here?

Comment: well, I think joining the dots is essentially proving, at least some local version of Stoke's theorem. I understand that there is a gap between the definition, via essentially a formula, of the exterior differential, and the intuition, which is essentially the local version of Stoke's theorem. Historically, it came from generalizing several lower dimensional special cases, and is thus non-trivial. Many books discuss it. I would guess you could find it in some volume of Spivak, one of Lee's books, possibly in Boothby's book and many other places.

Comment: Perhaps my recent answer in Carlo's reference link "one" may join your dots.