# Alternative characterization of the exterior derivative?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I was wondering whether the following commuting diagram property was enough to characterize the exterior derivative (although I'm suspicious. Is this answered somewhere in the literature? my question came about after posting a comment in [What is the exterior derivative intuitively?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21024/what-is-the-exterior-derivative-intuitively/56008#comment955571_56008))

Let $f$ be any smooth map $f:M\to N$ where $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifold and consider the map $f^*: A(N)\to A(M)$ between the spaces of smooth sections of the exterior form bundles $\Omega(N^*)$ and $\Omega(M^*)$, $A(N)$ and $A(M)$, associated to the manifolds $N$ and $M$. Then the exterior derivative is the unique map $d$ such that the following diagram commutes (and its properties follow from this characterization):

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A(N) @>d>> A(N)\\
    @V f^* V V @VV f^* V\\
    A(M)@>>d> A(M)
\end{CD}

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $d = 0$ makes your diagram commute...?

Comment: This (and linked paper) contains what you're after I believe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918949/characterization-of-the-exterior-derivative-d

Comment: The paper @PaulReynolds [references](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376900/alternative-characterization-of-the-exterior-derivative#comment955873_376900):  [Palais - Natural operations on differential forms](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-092-01/S0002-9947-1959-0116352-7).

Comment: The identity also makes your diagram commute! I think you further want to require that $d$ is a derivation of degree $1$, and even then I think you can at best hope to recover $d$ up to a scalar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and links, definitely want to exclude $0$ an the identity...

Comment: @PaulReynolds Definitely what I was thinking about, thank you!